# how to install flex and bison: error can not locate file

Tags: 13.04, software-center, update-manager

i tried to install flex and bison but i got this error : can not locate the file & also i use software center to do this but authenticate error occur.

i don't know which resource i should choose. when i run this command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

this is the result:

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/lucid/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080:
```

My environment:

```
$ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
https_proxy="https://127.0.0.1:8080/"
ftp_proxy="ftp://127.0.0.1:8080/"
socks_proxy="socks://127.0.0.1:8080/"

$ /etc/apt/apt.conf
Acquire::http::proxy "http://127.0.0.1:8080/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://127.0.0.1:8080/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://127.0.0.1:8080/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://127.0.0.1:8080/";
```

Comment: Looks like your proxy server that you run locally is down.

Comment: i do not know what is your meaning :( i do not use proxy server to connect to internet , tnx for your answer

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `cat /etc/environment` and `cat /etc/apt/apt.conf`.

Comment: i edit my question

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you on? You tagged 12.04, but your error is for 10.04.

Comment: my ubuntu version is 13.04

Comment: @user2524966 13.04 is well past End of Life, and is offtopic here.  However, this question is a duplicate of the one muru marked.  (We strongly recommend upgrading to a supported release, however)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your distribution is Ubuntu Lucid.

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In the open file, delete the content and paste this:

```
## Uncomment the following two lines to fetch updated software from the network
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid main restricted

## Uncomment the following two lines to fetch major bug fix updates produced
## after the final release of the distribution.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-updates main restricted

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'universe'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid universe

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Continue run in a terminal:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install flex bison
apt-get clean
```

If your distribution is not Ubuntu Lucid, change Lucid to appropriate name.

If none of this works

Download packages (Lucid):

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bison/bison_2.4.1.dfsg-3_i386.deb (32 bit)
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bison/bison_2.4.1.dfsg-3_amd64.deb (64 bit)
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/f/flex/flex_2.5.35-9_i386.deb (32 bit)
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/f/flex/flex_2.5.35-9_amd64.deb (64 bit)

And install them with:

```
sudo -i
cd /home/user/Downloads
dpkg -i *.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you have proxy settings configured. Assuming you don't need them, open System Settings, go to the Network section, set Proxy settings to None and click *Apply system wide*:

[image]

Comment: i do that but i got this error: <br/>    
      Package flex is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'flex' has no installation candidate